# How to create shared NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, rollup

I have an NPM package that I am creating in Typescript which just contains my type interfaces.

I currently have a folder structure like this:

```
project
│   index.ts
│
└───types
    │   restaurant.ts
    │   menus.ts
```

and package.json that points to the index file:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shared type definitions",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "source": "./index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

I can link this with another package in "project A" and all works well.

But as soon as I move my `index.ts` and type files into a directory called `src`, the link no longer works

```
Cannot find module 'my-package' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I have tried removing the symlink / reinstalling the linked package as well as updating my package.json file of my shared package to `"main": "./src/index.ts",` but to no avail

How am I supposed to create an NPM package which points to my src or even a dist file?

Comment: You should link the built index.js file and not your ts files in package.json.
https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm-89d93ff7bccd

Comment: I don't have a build index.js file as these are just TS interfaces

Comment: You should have one. How do you export your interfaces? If you dont need just add an empty one but more interesting is the generated d.ts file which you also have to link in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a monorepo project.

Take a look at [turborepo](https://turborepo.org/), which [does exactly what you want](https://youtu.be/flbz_5aMikw).

You can also try [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/), but I personally prefer the other one.